# How to delete particular data in a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

Hi the following is my document in mongodb, now i want to delete the data 
Kumar[] in the given document, I have used (update pop) and remove functions. one is deleting the inside data and the other is deleting the total document any help is appreciated in deleting the required data in document

```js
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("537d98c2a8357030c4f46cc0"),
        "name" : "karan",
        "address" : "hyd",
        "hobbies" : [ 
            "listeningmusic", 
            "chess"
        ],
        "friends" : [ 
            {
                "satish" : "school"
            }, 
            {
                "naresh" : "college"
            }, 
            {
                "dileep" : "school"
            }, 
            {
                "pavan" : "neighbour"
            }, 
            {
                "kumar" : "office"
            }
        ],
        "kumar" : []
    }
```

I have tried the following queries

```js
db.userdata.update({kumar:"office"},{$pull:{kumar:"office"}})

 db.userdata.remove({kumar:"office"},1)
```

Comment: Wait are you looking to remove the array or remove the data in the array?

Comment: If unsure, you should always check whether your query matches any document. `db.userdata.find({kumar:"office"})` actually returns nothing, so the partial update would not take place anyway. @Neil Lunn 's answer is correct for everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator, in combination with [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) within the query to match the document with the wrong field:

```js
db.userdata.update({ "kumar": { "$exists": 1 },{ "$unset": { "kumar": "" } })
```

That will remove the empty array you are showing in the document.